# post to wall with facebook sdk3.2 ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I write iphone application and I want to post on my facebook wall, I use facebook SDK 3.2 for ios.
Does anyone know how I do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) postWall:(NSString *)caption:(NSString *)description:(NSString *) name:(NSString *)link{



    NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       name, @"name",
                                       caption, @"caption",
                                       description, @"description",
                                      link,@"link",

                                       nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                 parameters:postParams
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error){}

     ];


}
```